# az vm create with managed disk results in "invalid usage for storage profile: create unmanaged OS disk created from generalized VHD"

Tags: azure

```
$ az vm create \
  --name=colemick-nixosdev3 \
  --resource-group=colemick-nixosdev3 \
  --ssh-key-value=ssh-rsa ...' \
  --size=Standard_D16s_v3 \
  --image=/subscriptions/aff271ee-e9be-4441-b9bb-42f5af4cbaeb/resourceGroups/aznixos/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/nixos-image-16.09.1694.019dcc3-x86_64-linux.vhd

invalid usage for storage profile: create unmanaged OS disk created from generalized VHD:
    missing: --os-type, --use-unmanaged-disk
```

The image points to a Managed Disk in my subscription. I know that the managed disk is backed by a valid VHD page blob.

The weird thing is that I had managed to boot a VM from a Managed Disk like this, made some tiny refactoring changes, and now can't get it to work again.

I can also post the script used to create that source managed disk, but it was roughly this:

- create storage account / container
- copy the blob into it
- create a MD using the blob URI as the source

Comment: Is there a difference between creating an "image" from a VHD Blob, versus creating an "image" from a Managed Disk reference?

Comment: Are you want to create new VM with OS disk(managed)?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT Yes, that's what I was trying to do... Thanks, but I got it. It's all due to bugs in the CLI. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is all sort of related to how Azure CLI was trying to sniff detect between disk references and blob URIs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6227

After working around the issues in that link (aka, by making sure the disk and image did not end with ".vhd") then I was able to create the VM as expected.